# Alternative to BCS in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, bcs, external-list

My requirements is to consume external data in SharePoint 2013. One of the option I know is SSIS, this is a lot of work. I wanted to know if you've achieved something similar using other methods.

Reason: SharePoint Designer is disabled.

Update: Looking for client side solutions.

Comment: Where this external data located (e.g. SQL server)? What type is it (e.g. database)? What do you need to do with the external data in SharePoint? What do you mean by "*Reason: SharePoint Designer is enabled.*"? What does this have to do with the fact that you need to access external data from SP?

Comment: Consume in what way? Other than BCS and External Content Types, I don't know that there is another built in option. When these do not cut it for me, I create a list that mirrors the external data (SQL table in my case) and use a Powershell script or C# program to "sync" the list up with the table, and run it on the scheduler. In my case, once a day is enough. Then I just use the list like any other SharePoint list (mainly for lookups).

Comment: @MihailPopa, Designer is disabled for security reasons. Imported data needs to have CURD operations enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question and comments, your issue is represented in creating an External Content Type without using SharePoint Designer because it's disabled in your organization for security reasons.

So in your case, you can easily create `Data Connectivity Model (Farm Solution Only)` using Visual Studio.

[image]

Once the solution is deployed, it will create an External Content Type that can be consumed in External List without using SharePoint Designer.

Check the detail steps at

- [External Content Type Using Visual Studio](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2013/08/09/external-content-type-walkthrough/)
- [Get started using the client object model with external data in SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/get-started-using-the-client-object-model-with-external-data-in-sharepoint#BCScsom_Tasks)

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful but I'm are looking for client side solutions.

Comment: you are welcome, but you don't mention CSOM in your question or your tag. anyway check the updated answer with a link that will help you to work with external data using CSOM,

Comment: If the OP could do this then they could also just enable SharePoint Designer.

Comment: What's the relation? The OP didn't mention he can't use VS and at the same time the SharePoint designer is disabled for security purpose as he described, so What do u think ?!!

Comment: Guys, What is OP?

Answer (score 2):

@M.Qassas solution is the best one. However if you are looking for an alternative solution to BCS and SSIS, you can create a console app. Add your data sync logic between SharePoint and external system. Finally schedule it in Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Admad, If i'm not wrong, It'll still be code based solution. I'm looking for Client side solutions.

Comment: @vikbehal Sorry, I am not aware of any solution apart from SSIS, BCS and code based. Are you okay for third party solutions? If yes, check simego data synchronisation studio https://www.simego.com/solutions/sharepoint-integration. It's a no-code solution to sync data between SharePoint and external systems including SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to consume your data using an add-in-scoped external content type by creating an add-in project and an oData ASP.NET Web API proxy service.

You could also build the CRUD operations manually in JavaScript with AJAX calls to the API, and inject the code into a SharePoint page.

Comment: Can you pls. provide more insights?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, but if you're not looking so much to integrate the data into SharePoint as you are just displaying it, you could use a page viewer webpart and/or iframe in a content editor webpart to embed a page on the other system that allows all of these capabilities (provided that solution has them, or you can easily create a UI for it). If you had single sign-on between the solutions, it could be seamless to your end user. It just comes down to how integrated you want it to be, but sometimes when another system is doing its job just fine, it's best to let it continue doing that, versus recreating the wheel.

Comment: To summarize your answer capabilities are given SharePoint hosted apps.

Comment: Not exactly. It could be done that way, or it could just be an iframe. I was thinking the latter if you already have a system that does what you need it to.